# Destructured parameters causing eslint // {age, name} is missing in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

**i am using javascript**
destructuring like this will pick properties from the incoming argument object

```
export default function App() {
    const data={name:"name",age:"age"}

    return(
        <>
           <SHow data={data}/>
        </>
)}

////eslint error 'age' is missing in props validationeslintreact/prop-types (parameter) age: any

function SHow({name,age}) {**/////eslint error 'age' and  'age' is missing in props**

    return(
        <>
            <h1>{name}</h1>
            <h1>{age}</h1>
        </>
)}
```

the code is working properly
so why es lint showing /////eslint error 'age' and  'age' is missing in props

i tryed this but i don't want create new variable for each component

```
function SHow(prop) {
    **const {name,age} =prop**
    return(
        <>
            <h1>{name}</h1>
            <h1>{age}</h1>
        </>
)}
```

//edit
even after spreading `<SHow {...data}/>` it still  showing
[image]

Comment: _"the code is working properly"_ I sincerely doubt that

Comment: ... in fact, I can prove it ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-jasper-pcsj2p?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3):

The issue is you're only passing a single prop named `data` with the original.

Try either spreading the props

```jsx
<SHow {...data} />
```

which is the equivalent of

```jsx
<SHow name={name} age={age} />
```

or destructuring the `data` prop

```js
function SHow({ data: { name, age } }) {
  // ...
}
```

---

Sounds like you've got the ESLint [react/prop-types](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md) rule enabled but you're not defining `propTypes` at all.

React [no longer recommends](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) using `propTypes`...

> PropTypes aren’t commonly used in modern React. Use TypeScript for static type checking.

For your JavaScript project, I'd either disable the rule or include the [prop-types library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) and define types accordingly

```jsx
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

function SHow({ name, age }) {
  // ...
}

SHow.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  age: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: Sounds like you've got the ESLint [react/prop-types](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md) rule enabled but you're not defining `propTypes` at all.

Answer (score 1):

The prop you are passing is data. Try this :

```
export default function App() {
const data={name:"name",age:"age"}

return(
    <>
       <SHow data={data}/>
    </>
)}

function SHow({data}) {

return(
    <>
        <h1>{data.name}</h1>
        <h1>{data.age}</h1>
    </>
)}
```